# Jaeger traces not capturing for spring-data

Tags: spring-data, jaeger

Jaeger traces to spring-boot application are not able to capture traces for the DB calls made using spring-data. All other calls like RESTTemplate are able to have the traces captured.

Using springboot version 2.2.2.RELEASE and added below jaeger dependencies,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any additional dependencies are missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your dependencies and use the following one that will include also the instrumentation you need

```
<dependency>
 <groupid>io.opentracing.contrib</groupid>
 <artifactid>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactid>
 <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```